# Showing full mobile menu at top of page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, menu, display

I have a mobile menu that hides a partial section on scroll down, but on scroll up shows the full menu. That part works great, but the issue is when the page is scrolled down and then scrolled back up to the top, the full menu does not display. I would like the menu to display when the page is at the top. I've tried adding

```
    if (currentScrollPos = 0) {
      document.getElementbyId("site-header").style.top = "0";
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the full code, showing / hiding parts of the header:

```
    <script>
                
            if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 700) {
                var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
                    window.onscroll = function() {
                var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
                    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
                    document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "-40px";
                        }
                        prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
                        }
            }
            </script>
```